# ns0 is an undeclared prefix while Deserialising XML

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, xml-deserialization

I am trying to De-serialize XML below to C# classes:

```
<StaffingOrder xmlns="NameSpaceName">
  <ReportingRequirements>
    <ns0:ManagerName>__MANAGER_NAME</ns0:ManagerName>
    <ns0:SupervisorName>__SUPERVISOR_NAME</ns0:SupervisorName>
  </ReportingRequirements>
  <Comments>Comment</Comments>      
</StaffingOrder>
```

But while deserializing I am getting following Error:

```
Error: There was an error processing 'Test.xml'.
  - 'ns0' is an undeclared prefix
```

How can i deserialize ns0 tags.

Comment: Deserializing is usually called parsing. And you can't parse XML if it's ill-formed. Find out where this not-XML was created and fix it at source.

Answer (score 3):

The XML document is not namespace-well-formed because the prefix **ns0** is not bound to any namespace. This is why it cannot be parsed.

It can be bound to a namespace of your choice with an **xmlns:ns0** attribute in any tag around its use, like so:

```
<StaffingOrder
    xmlns="NameSpaceName"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.com/some/namespace">
  <ReportingRequirements>
    <ns0:ManagerName>__MANAGER_NAME</ns0:ManagerName>
    <ns0:SupervisorName>__SUPERVISOR_NAME</ns0:SupervisorName>
  </ReportingRequirements>
  <Comments>Comment</Comments>      
</StaffingOrder>
```